# What is the type annotation for a Flask view?

Tags: python, flask, python-typing

I want to add type annotations to a view function that returns a call to `redirect`. What does `redirect` return, and how do I add an annotation for that to my view function?

I thought it might be `str`, or the `redirect` function, but I'm not sure.

```py
def setalarm() -> redirect:
    # Retrieves the information to create new alarms.
    return redirect("/")
```

Comment: [The docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.redirect) seem to suggest that `redirect` returns a `Response` object, specifically a [`werkzeug.wrappers.Response`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Response) if you don't specify. If that's the case, it would be `. . . -> werkzeug.wrappers.Response`, once you've imported that class. I'd write an answer, but I don't know anything about Flask.

Answer (score 13):

The straightforward answer is to annotate your view with whatever you're writing it to return. In your specific example, `redirect` returns an instance of `werkzeug.wrappers.Response`.

```py
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response

def set_alarm() -> Response:
    return redirect()
```

---

Rather than figuring out what any given function returns in order to annotate your view, it might seem easier to come up with a `Union` annotation that represents anything a Flask view is allowed to return. However, Flask doesn't provide typing information, and its dynamic nature makes representing the possibilities difficult.

By default, a Flask view can return:

- A `str` or `bytes`.
- A subclass of `werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse`.
- A tuple in one of these forms, where `data` is any of the other types a Flask view can return:

  - `(data,)`
  - `(data, status)`, where `status` can be either an `int` or a `str` or `bytes`.
  - `(data, headers)`, where `headers` is either a dict, iterable of `(key, value)` tuples, or a `werkzeug.datastructures.Headers` object.
  - `(data, status, headers)`
- A `dict` to be converted to JSON. The values should be types that `app.json_encoder` supports.
- A WSGI callable.

Flask can support more or different return types by overriding the `Flask.make_response` method. The data it can serialize to JSON can be extended by overriding `Flask.json_encoder`. If you have customized Flask's behavior you'll need to customize the type information as well.

Here's a `view_return_type` that represents the possible return types from a Flask view, [ignoring JSON typing](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182). Once you define the type, you can annotate any view with it.

```py
import typing as t
from werkzeug.datastructures import Headers
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseResponse

_str_bytes = t.Union[str, bytes]
_data_type = t.Union[
    _str_bytes,
    BaseResponse,
    t.Dict[str, t.Any],
    t.Callable[
        [t.Dict[str, t.Any], t.Callable[[str, t.List[t.Tuple[str, str]]], None]], t.Iterable[bytes]
    ],
]
_status_type = t.Union[int, _str_bytes]
_headers_type = t.Union[
    Headers, t.Dict[_str_bytes, _str_bytes], t.Iterable[t.Tuple[_str_bytes, _str_bytes]],
]

view_return_type = t.Union[
    _data_type,
    t.Tuple[_data_type],
    t.Tuple[_data_type, _status_type],
    t.Tuple[_data_type, _headers_type],
    t.Tuple[_data_type, _status_type, _headers_type],
]
```

```py
@app.route("/users/<int:id>/")
def user_detail(id: int) -> view_return_type:
    ...
```

Answer (score 11):

In Flask 2 you can use `flask.typing.ResponseReturnValue`.

```
from flask.typing import ResponseReturnValue


@app.get("/")
def index() -> ResponseReturnValue:
    return "OK"
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find docs on it, but the source is [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/cb825687a592709f902f3d320d93987a0546fd28/src/flask/typing.py#L34).